# Raspberry Pi 2 on-topic?

Tags: support, on-off-topic

[On-Topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is not specific about versions, so is it correct to assume that any Raspberry model (A, A+, B, B+, 2) is on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I just found [rpi2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpi2), so it doesn't seem to be popular yet, but on-topic.

Comment: For future reference: [tag:rpi2] has been renamed to [tag:pi-2] for a consistent naming scheme, see http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/720/pi-model-tag-naming-is-not-consistent